# Array shuffle every 3 elements

Tags: php, html, arrays

This is a example of my array:

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c' 
      'd', 'e', 'f'
      'g', 'h', 'i'];
```

I print them in three lines using for loop and html.

**Now I want to shuffle them to be:**

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'
      'g', 'h', 'i'
      'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

**Then:**

```
$x = ['g', 'h', 'i'
      'd', 'e', 'f'
      'a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Actually I want to shuffle the array printing every 3 elements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

In your case:

```
$chunked = array_chunk($x, 3);
shuffle($chunked);
$result = [];
foreach($chunked as $array)
    foreach($array as $item)
        $result[] = $item;
```

Then the `$result` is that you want.

Working example: http://phpio.net/s/1m4w

Comment: This will shuffle like I want no matter how big is my array?

Comment: Yep. Test it on phpio.net

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't return what I want.. I want to arrange them three by three

Comment: Update your question. Script I've posted returns exactly what you wanted

Comment: Oops, my fault, I forgot to flatten array. Updated my answer.